# What is wrong with my parser?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I made a parser in Haskell for [Euler Problem 54](http://projecteuler.net/problem=54). All my parsers seam to work, except for my full file parser. It is a `ReadP` parser, and it parses it to `[(Hand, Hand)]`, where I created a Hand type. It currently parses the file to `[]`. I have the source code:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP as Par
import qualified Data.List as L
import qualified Control.Monad as M
import qualified Data.Map as D
import qualified Control.Applicative as A

data Suit=C|D|H|S deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
data Card=Card Int Suit deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
data Hand=Hand [Card] deriving (Show, Eq)

ranks=D.fromList [('2', 2), ('3', 3), ('4', 4), ('5', 5), ('6', 6), ('7', 7), ('8', 8),
 ('9', 9), ('T', 10), ('J', 11), ('Q', 12), ('K', 13), ('A', 14)]

allPar=readP_to_S
fstPar s=fst . head . (allPar s)

parCard=do
    rank <- M.liftM (ranks D.!) get
    suit <- M.liftM (read . (:[])) get
    return $ Card rank suit

parHand=do
    first <-parCard
    rest  <-M.replicateM 4 (char ' ' >> parCard)
    return $ Hand $ first:rest

parFile=do
    r<-sepBy (return (,) `M.ap` parHand `M.ap` (char ' ' >> parHand)) (char '\n')
    eof --I have tested with and without this line.
    return r
```

And when I try it (both with and without `eof`) I get:

```
λ <*Main>: fstPar parFile `M.liftM` readFile "poker.txt"
[]
```

Note: I know `ReadP` is inefficient, but it is a small file, and I just wanted something quick.

Update: It was suggested that I try it by having it parse eof after the initial parse. I have updated my question to reflect this, but it gives the same result either way.

Answer (score 2):

`ReadP` is giving you multiple parses, and you're selecting the simplest one: not parsing at all. Given

```
KC QD 3S 4H 6S 2D 3D 4D 5D AD
AD 5D 4D 3D 2D 6S 4H 3S QD KC
```

as input, running that through your parser yields three parses:

```
[ ([],"KC QD 3S 4H 6S 2D 3D 4D 5D AD\nAD 5D 4D 3D 2D 6S 4H 3S QD KC")
, ([(Hand [Card 13 C,Card 12 D,Card 3 S,Card 4 H,Card 6 S],Hand [Card 2 D,Card 3 D,Card 4 D,Card 5 D,Card 14 D])],"\nAD 5D 4D 3D 2D 6S 4H 3S QD KC")
, ([(Hand [Card 13 C,Card 12 D,Card 3 S,Card 4 H,Card 6 S],Hand [Card 2 D,Card 3 D,Card 4 D,Card 5 D,Card 14 D]),(Hand [Card 14 D,Card 5 D,Card 4 D,Card 3 D,Card 2 D],Hand [Card 6 S,Card 4 H,Card 3 S,Card 12 D,Card 13 C])],"")
]
```

Out of those, you probably want the last one, since it's the one that has no leftover input. The easiest way to do this would be to have your parser fail if it's left with any leftover input. Fortunately, that's easy:

```
fstPar (parFile A.<* eof) `M.liftM` readFile "poker.txt"
```

That is, just have it run `eof` at the end. Note that now `poker.txt` can't have a new line at the end of the file. It shouldn't be too difficult to write a little bit more code to skip any amount of whitespace at the end of the file.

Comment: It gives me `*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list` for the entire file. Also, if I used a monad and put eof after the main parse, it gives an empty list. Look at the update.

Comment: @PyRulez: I looked at your code more closely and realized it wanted two hands on a line. After fixing the input, the code in your question works perfectly.

Comment: Wait, you actually modified poker.txt?

Comment: @PyRulez: Yes; I was giving it invalid input before. Your code accepts two hands a line, and my previous input had only one hand a line. Once I fixed my input, your code worked just fine.

Comment: It still fails with poker.txt from the problem.

Comment: @PyRulez: I just got the `poker.txt` from projecteuler.net and again, it works just fine. Have you made sure that the file has no newline at the end? As I mentioned in my answer, your code currently does not allow for that, so it must not occur.

Comment: I did, I will check again.